# How to automatically duplicate hyperlinks so that it links to the same duplicated page and not the original in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula

I have a long table with sections in a Google Sheets sheet. The first four rows are frozen and have hyperlinks to all the sections in the table so I can access those sections fast. I need to create a new duplicate sheet every week, but hyperlinks in duplicate sheets still link to the original page if I don't manually change them. How can I make it so when duplicating the template sheet, the hyperlinks would automatically link to the table sections in the duplicated sheet and not the original?

Made a quick example of the sheet. Duplicated the TEMP and all the hyperlinks there still link to the TEMP page. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jIdWY583ZQwau10NAskK4u7RjaPNKJxCTk5DYippV8Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Made a quick example of the sheet. Duplicated the TEMP and all the hyperlinks there still link to the TEMP page. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jIdWY583ZQwau10NAskK4u7RjaPNKJxCTk5DYippV8Y/edit?usp=sharing